# Which approach is better to improve complexity with dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary, time-complexity

I'm writing code to handle item inventories for a game that hold items object. Each inventory has a `MaxSlots` property that indicates how much items it can hold. Once it reaches it's maximum capcaity, the user can't add more items to it.

The game has an Equipped inventory that holds the equipped items to the character and a regular inventory bag that holds items. Both inventories can hold items, but the equipped one just represents the items that are visually equipped on the character.

Each item has a `Slot` property that indicates where the item is located inside the inventory. In the game, equipped inventories have negative slots to differiniate between equipped and normal inventories.

Approach 1:

```
public Dictionary<short, Item> Inventory { get; private set; }
```

In that way, you can add items and the property acts as both regular and equipped inventory, but if the index is negative then you know the item is equipped.

Approach 2:

```
public Dictionary<InventoryType, Dictionary<short, Item>> Inventory { get; private set; }
```

When the user wants to add a new item, we need to check if the inventory has reached it's capacity. My friend says his way (approach #2) is better, because the complexity to check the count is `O(1)`, while mine is `O(N)` because I have to check if the key is negative, like so:

```
Inventory.Where(i => i.Key < 0).Count
```

Which approach is better and is he right? Please note the maximum items a user can hold is 100, so I believe the complexity doesn't matter because it's a really low effort. Also note that we cannot change the design of the game, only the server aspect.

Comment: I'm kinda not really sure why you aren't just using a list or array (or an array within an Inventory class that tracks the number of items in the inventory). If you model your player too, then the player has various slots where they can eg hold a sword and a shield, or a sword and a gun, but not a sword and a gun and a shield (only two hands), so "equipped" is a feature of whether the Player is using an item in one of its slots (hands) ? Ultimately, I'm not sure what benefit using a Dictionary gives you here, as it's intended for fast lookup but you don't sound like you're looking anything up

Comment: You are instead, risking getting into `Dictionary<Dictionary<Dictionary>>>` hell because you're trying to model N sets of related properties that should have their own class, as a chain of Key:Value(Key:Value(Key:Value)) pairs